# How to speed up the generating process of a cmake project with vcpkg?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, vcpkg

I'm now using cmake with vcpkg list mode(vcpkg.json), and every time I try to rebuild the project will be very slow(about 20s), is there any possible way to speed up this process?

here are the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project(G C CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

# SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O3 -Wall")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb")

find_package(absl CONFIG REQUIRED)

if(NOT DEFINED BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE)
else()
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${BUILD_TYPE})
endif()

message(STATUS "BUILD_TYPE: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ SOURCE)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test/ TEST_SOURCE)
 
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)

add_library(sourceLib SHARED ${SOURCE})

# add_executable(out ${SOURCE} )
add_executable(test ${TEST_SOURCE})

target_link_libraries(test UnitTest++ sourceLib absl::flat_hash_map)
```

and here are my project structure:

```
../
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── __pycache__
├── bin
├── data
├── inc
├── py
├── src
├── test
└── vcpkg.json
```

here are the output of command : cmake ../ -B .

```
-- Running vcpkg install
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-linux...
All requested packages are currently installed.
Restored 0 package(s) from /home/orrinn/.cache/vcpkg/archives in 1.63 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Total install time: 9.98 us
abseil provides CMake targets:

    # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
    find_package(absl CONFIG REQUIRED)
    # note: 170 additional targets are not displayed.
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE absl::any absl::log absl::base absl::bits)

-- Running vcpkg install - done
-- BUILD_TYPE: debug
-- Configuring done (25.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/orrinn/Code/a/graph_match/bin
```

is there any possible way to speed up this process?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project you can try and set number of parallel jobs with `-j` to see if it improves.

Comment: thanks for reply but the process of generating buildsystem still very slow, and the build process is quite fast(make -j or cmake --build . -j), is there any possible way to speed up the generating process?

Comment: Why are you re-generating so many times? You should only have to do it once. Then you just rerun make or ninja or whatever to rebuild.

Comment: Because  I need to build them with different g++ optimization flag, for debug is O1 with -g opetion and for test is O3.

Comment: BTW: `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` needs to be set before `project()`. `if(NOT DEFINED BUILD_TYPE)` is also wrong. So many bugs ....

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that `aux_source_directory` is expensive as it walks the entire tree collection source files. In CMake it is recommended to explicitly list source files for targets instead of calling `aux_source_directory` or `file(GLOB ...)`.

Comment: I tried to list all sources but it doesnt work for me. It's still very slow(about 18s).

Comment: You can try using `ccmake` or `cmake-gui` which separate configuring and generation steps. This might give a hint what part of the process takes so much time.